Web animation API-MDN web Docs-Monzilla
Web animation API composition accumulate.what is a web animation composition.what is a  animation what is a web animator
The web animation API allows for synchronizing and timming changes to the presentation of a web page,i.e animation of DOM elements.It does so by combining  two models:the timming models and the animation models.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
